# JSON Path - is there a way to only return a specific number of filtered elements?

Tags: jsonpath

I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do this purely with JSON path, but figured I'd ask any how.
When applying a filter on an array within the object, is there a way to specify to return only the first n elements?

e.g., working of the example from https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Given an object like this:

```
    { "store": {
    "book": [ 
      { "category": "reference",
        "author": "Nigel Rees",
        "title": "Sayings of the Century",
        "price": 8.95
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
        "title": "Sword of Honour",
        "price": 12.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "Herman Melville",
        "title": "Moby Dick",
        "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
        "price": 8.99
      },
      { "category": "fiction",
        "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
        "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
        "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
        "price": 22.99
      }
    ],
    "bicycle": {
      "color": "red",
      "price": 19.95
    }
  }
}
```

and running a JSON path expression like so:

```
$..book[?(@.price<10)]
```

Will return 2 objects:

```
[
   {
      "category" : "reference",
      "author" : "Nigel Rees",
      "title" : "Sayings of the Century",
      "price" : 8.95
   },
   {
      "category" : "fiction",
      "author" : "Herman Melville",
      "title" : "Moby Dick",
      "isbn" : "0-553-21311-3",
      "price" : 8.99
   }
]
```

Is there any syntax that results in JSON Path only returning 1 of the objects?

Comment: This is a great idea.  We're actually working on formalizinga JSON Path specification at https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base.  I would suggest opening an issue with your idea.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a function on it's own. I would work around this like so...

```
const filterBooks = $..book[?(@.price<10)]
const firstBook = $.. filterBooks[0]
const lastBook = $.. filterBooks[-1:]
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware I can use JavaScript to work around it : ) Just asking if there was a JSON Path native way to do this.